# Concat multiple files using SED

Tags: windows, unix, sed

I have a txt file with list of filenames, which contains file path. How to concat all files to a single file?

EX:

```
One.txt content >> first file content
two.txt content >> second file content
three.txt content >> third file content

allFiles.txt contains these the below lines
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
```

I need to concat allFiles.txt to a output.txt file which contains the below lines

```
first file content
second file content
third file content
```

Comment: Do you really need sed? `cat allFiles.txt | xargs cat` should do it.

Comment: cat allFiles.txt | xargs cat >> output.txt. It works

Answer (score 0):

```
while read fname
do
 sed '1' "$fname" >> newfile.txt # You need to append so '>>'
done<allFiles.txt
```

But if you need all the `*.txt` files

It can be as simple as

```
shopt -s globstar
sed '' **/*.txt 1>>/outfile 2>/dev/null # errors for .txt directories are suppressed
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Specific files only, not all files is same directory. So created a txt file which contains those file names.

Comment: @Neo : Then my first solution is for you. Please accept it if it fits the requirement.